# Xaml template not applied to page in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am making an application for windows phone which uses page navigation. Because the layout of each page is similar I made a custom base page class for all the pages in the application. The problem is that the template is not applied to the template page class.

This is how I defined my template for the base page in a generic.xaml file:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TfsExplorer.Client.UI"
xmlns:common="using:TfsExplorer.Client.UI.Common">

<Style TargetType="common:ModuleTemplatePage" x:Key="Omfg">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="common:ModuleTemplatePage">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="80*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="500*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ListView x:Name="LstViewNavigationHistory" Grid.Row="0">
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListView>
                    <Frame x:Name="FrameModuleContent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1"
                           Width="400" Content="{TemplateBinding ModuleContent}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

All the custom content goes into the frames content property. I have the dependency property set up to update the content of the frame with the new value if it's changed.

Now in a code file I defined the base class along with a new dependency property:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "FrameModuleContent", Type = typeof(Frame))]
public class ModuleTemplatePage : Page
{
    #region Static Fields

    private static void ModuleContentPropertyChangedCallback(
        DependencyObject dependencyObject, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var templatePage = dependencyObject as ModuleTemplatePage;

        if (templatePage != null)
        {
            var contentFrame = templatePage.GetTemplateChild("FrameModuleContent") as Frame;

            if (contentFrame != null)
            {
                contentFrame.Content = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors and Destructors

    public ModuleTemplatePage()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ModuleTemplatePage);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public ModuleTemplateContent ModuleContent
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(ModuleContentProperty) as ModuleTemplateContent;
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ModuleContentProperty, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion
    }
```

Bur this does not work. No template is applied to the pages. I overrode the OnTemplateApply methods to listen when a template is applied and it never happens.

I declared these pages in another assembly from the main windows phone assembly and I added a reference to the generic.xml to the App.xaml like this:

```
<Application
x:Class="TfsExplorer.Client.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TfsExplorer.Client">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <ImageBrush x:Key="HubBackgroundImageBrush" ImageSource="Assets/HubBackground.png" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                <ImageBrush x:Key="HubBackgroundImageBrush" ImageSource="{x:Null}" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///TfsExplorer.Client.UI/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The assembly that contains the generic.xaml file is called TfsExplorer.Client.UI and I know it is referenced properly because I got a dropdown of all the elements in the assembly when adding the generic.xaml in visual studio.